# access variable from another form

Tags: c#

i have 2 forms one for login and another one for calling a function that depends on the login.

FORM1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static public string userId, userPassword;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Program.AllStudents.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                Program.studentdata student = Program.LoginStudent(userId);
                if (student.password == userPassword)
                {
                    Form3 studentcommands = new Form3();
                    studentcommands.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password", "Error",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password", "Error",
     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                this.Close();
            }

        }
```

what if i want to access the object called student in another form?
what should i do?

Comment: Search for any of the million duplicates of this exact same question.

Comment: This is a question I've even asked myself and see it asked so often. Go check another answer but for convenience, there are two options AFAIK. Firstly, make your object public, access it by Form1.objectName. Or your second option being to pass the object to your second form as a parameter.

Comment: Just for my curiosity, is this a class assignment?  Same question was posed a couple hours ago.

Comment: I honestly think you should start by the beginning... And that's learning OOP basics, because I don't like where your code is going. There are plenty of resources on the net, for example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mkagrahari/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-concepts-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: The static suggestion above should only be used if you actually need a static property.  Otherwise reference the actual instance.

Comment: @Trey good point, fixed it

Comment: if i make it public by doing this
 public Program.studentdata student = Program.LoginStudent(userId);
it shows error which says Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Program.studentdata' is less accessible than field 'Form1.student' gui @J.Doe

Comment: Ensure the containing classes/forms are public as well.

Comment: yep everything is public @J.Doe

Comment: I'm going to need to see the form containing this code to help further

Comment: here you go
http://pastebin.com/cBXfsUBL
contains program.cs and form.cs
@J.Doe

Comment: change `static class Program` to `public static class Program` on line 12 of your paste

Comment: Just make everything public so your code becomes a time bomb. @user3229833, you are basically removing encapsulation from the OOP principles.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a `Public property` of type Student in this form and access it from others by using `Form1.Propertyname`

Read more about properties in this [MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx)

Or just declare your object as `Public`